# Using a FreeTDS ODBC driver to connect Linux PHP to a SQL Server

Tags: php, sql, sql-server, odbc

I just set up my freetds.conf file with a new virtual account to connect to a SQL Server database but I am not sure when and where I tell my PHP script which database to connect to below are my settings

odbc.ini

```
[McDo]
ServerName = server1
Driver  = FreeTDS
Description = MyServer 
Trace   = Yes
```

freetds.conf

```
[server1]
host = 66.111.xxx.xxx
port = 1433
tds version = 7.0
```

And here is my PHP connect script. Now sure where I tell the script to connect to which database.

```
putenv('ODBCINI=/etc/odbc.ini');

$connect = odbc_connect("server1", "username", "password");

//$query = "SELECT name_ID  FROM ext_name";

if(!$connect){
echo "not connected";

}else{
echo "connected";
}

odbc_close($connect);
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The php manual shows:

```
// Microsoft SQL Server using the SQL Native Client 10.0 ODBC Driver - allows connection to SQL 7, 2000, 2005 and 2008
$connection = odbc_connect("Driver={SQL Server Native Client 10.0};Server=$server;Database=$database;", $user, $password);
```

Comment: The ```SQL Server Native Client``` is exclusive for Windows. The author was explicit on the title about the SO that he is using.

Comment: This solution not apply to Linux